# 2D ndarray: row-wise operations

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2D numpy array, with example shape:

```
>>> a.shape
(48, 160)
```

and I want to do simple operation between elements or each row, like `a[0] - a[1]` but for every row against all other rows.

I know how to do it simply by using `for` loop and iterating rows, but I was wondering if there is some numpy slicing specific instruction, that can do this without using `for` loops

Comment: There's a great module called itertools which will give you all the combinations of a list of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use broadcasting magic to do this.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(12).reshape((4, 3))
b = np.arange(15).reshape((5, 3))
diff = a[np.newaxis, :, :] - b[:, np.newaxis, :]
diff.shape
# (5, 4, 3)
```

[This](http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc) is a good broadcasting tutorial. In this case I make a (1, 4, 3) and b (5, 1, 3) and I get a result that's (5, 4, 3), the difference of every row pair in a and b.

Comment: Thanks, it works great. I'll need to study broadcasting to get the meaning, but it's easier when there is solution and a docs. Cheers